# How to estimate the relative motion using kinematic equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

## Background

I am reading the following thesis:

> Todosiev, E.P., 1963. The action point model of the driver-vehicle
>   system.

On page 9 it describes the relative motion between 2 cars as follows:
$$ h = 0.5\cdot A\cdot t^2 + v_0\cdot t + h_0 \tag 1$$
where,

\begin{align}A = \text{Constant relative acceleration} &= \text{lead car acceleration} - \text{following car acceleration}\\ t &= \text{time}\\ v_0 = \text{initial relative velocity} &= \text{lead car initial velocity - following car initial velocity}\\ h_0 &= \text{initial headway i.e. the distance gap between the 2 cars}\end{align}

After differentiating the above equation with respect to time, an expression for time is obtained which is substituted in the above equation to get following:

$$ h = {v^2}/{2A} + K\tag 2$$
where,
$$ K = h_0 - {v_0^2}/{2A}$$

## Estimation of h

I estimated h using both Eqns. 1 and 2. I assumed an initial relative velocity of -8 m/s, initial headway of 150 m, time as 1 second and relative acceleration of 2 m/s2. For relative velocity, v, I selected random values between -8 and 7.1.  Following figure shows the example trajectory from the thesis on left and the one I estimated on right.

[image]

## Problem

I am confused why Eqn. 1 did not yield the exact same result as Eqn. 2? In Eqn.1 I selected $v_0$ in every time step as the previous relative velocity. Also, the time t was selected as 1 second. In Eqn. 2 K is added which depends on $v_0$. But as seen in the left figure, $K$ is a constant, so I only used the  $v_0 = -8 ~\mathrm{m/s}$ for computing $K.$ My question is why the two equations result in different trajectories? Which approach is correct and why?

Comment: As @JohnRennie says, you have not described the problem which the author is trying to solve.  Without it, making sense of your question is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations you give are examples of the [SUVAT equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion), which are generally written as:

$$\begin{align}
s &= ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \\
v^2 &= u^2 + 2as
\end{align}$$

where using your notation $s=h-h_0$ and $u=v_0$.

Let's take your first equation:

$$ h = h_0 + ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag{1} $$

The problem is that this relates the distance $h$ to time, and you want it as a function of velocity. Since velocity is just the derivative of distance with repect to time we can differentiate your equation to get:

$$ v = \frac{dh}{dt} = u + at $$

which is another of the SUVAT equations. We can rearrange this to get:

$$ t = \frac{v-u}{a} $$

and then substitute for $t$ in your equation (1) to get:

$$ h = h_0 + u\left(\frac{v-u}{a}\right) + \tfrac{1}{2}a\left(\frac{v-u}{a}\right)^2 $$

And if we work thorough this equation term by term it simplifies to:

$$ h = h_0 + \frac{v^2-u^2}{2a} \tag{2} $$

and this is just your second equation. So this shows that the two equations are equavalent in the sense that one can be derived from the other. Both equations describe the same trajectory.

I assume you are using some form of numerical integration to obtain the $h:v$ curve for the first equation, and obviously the flaw is in your method of integration. However you don't give anough detail about what you are doing for us to pinpoint your mistake.